# How to dynamically set progress bar value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

On my tutorial website, I'm using jQuery UI progress bars not as bars that will change, but as images to display to show the user how far they are through the tutorial. Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(.progressbar).progressbar({
    value: 50
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jQueryUI.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jQueryUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/index.js"></script>

<body>
  Lots of stuff here
  <div class="progressbar"></div>
  <span style="text-align: center">50% complete</span>
  Lots more stuff here
</body>
```

However, what I want it to do is have multiple progress bars with different values. I want to have a class for the progress bars, and a custom attribute for its value. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(.progressbar).progressbar({
    value: $(.progressbar).attr("data-progress-value");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jQueryUI.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jQueryUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/index.js"></script>

<body>
  Lots of stuff here
  <div class="progressbar" data-progress-value="33"></div>
  <span style="text-align: center">33% complete</span> Lots more stuff here
  <div class="progressbar" data-progress-value="67"></div>
  <span style="text-align: center">67% complete</span> More stuff here
  <div class="progressbar" data-progress-value="90"></div>
  <span style="text-align: center">90% complete</span>
</body>
```

I know this code won't work though, because the jQuery docs say .attr and all similar functions only get the attribute of the first of the set.

**Is something like this possible in jQuery?**

Or, for the XY problem showing here, **If this is not possible, how can I dynamically set static progress bars?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly simple in an `each()` where you have access to each element instance before initializing plugin for that element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.progressbar').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.progressbar({
      value: $el.data("progress-value")
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


Lots of stuff here
<div class="progressbar" data-progress-value="33"></div>
<span style="text-align: center">33% complete</span> Lots more stuff here
<div class="progressbar" data-progress-value="67"></div>
<span style="text-align: center">67% complete</span> More stuff here
<div class="progressbar" data-progress-value="90"></div>
<span style="text-align: center">90% complete</span>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: What do the `|| 0` and the `+` before `$el$ do?

Comment: Value needs to be number... `attr()` returns string. The `|| 0` is for default in case attribute not defined or not a number

Comment: changed it to use `data()` which returns a number.

Answer (score 1):

Old post ik but this is what is working for me:

- NOTE: progress tag is defined since html 5
- NOTE2: You can smooth out the "animation" by tweaking the delay times.

```js
let progress = 0;
let timeoutSec = 10;
/**
 * This will update indefinetly and will run "yourRepeatetUpdate()" func every "10" sec
 * Time progress is displayed every update in <progress id="progressTillUpdate" ...></progress> html elem
 */
setInterval(
    (function () {
        console.log("Progress: " + progress + "/" + timeoutSec)
        document.getElementById("progressTillUpdate").max = timeoutSec;
        document.getElementById("progressTillUpdate").value = progress; // Does not update for some reason

        if (progress == timeoutSec) {yourRepeatetUpdate()}
        progress = (progress < timeoutSec) ? progress + 1 : 0; // Loop after timeoutSec 
}), 1*1000); // Updates every second

async function yourRepeatetUpdate() {
  /*code*/
};
```

```html
<style>
progress {
   animation-duration: 1s;
}
</style>


<progress id="progressTillUpdate" value="0" max="100" style="width: 100%;height:20px;"> 
  Progress bar 
</progress>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be updating the progress bar, only printing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional class unique to each progress bar, like pb1, pb2 etc.

Then just

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(.pb1).progressbar({
    value: 75
  });
$(.pb2).progressbar({
    value: 50
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I was looking for something reusable for different HTML files where the values might be different.

Comment: Yeah I like @charlietfl answer better in this scenario.